# Using bisect.insort to insert an item into a list, which is a part of a list of lists

Tags: python, list, insert

I'm trying to manage a list of several lists and each one should be sorted at all times, but I can't insert items into each list separately.

I had a list of n lists

```
arr = [[]]*n
```

I was trying to use

```
bisect.insort(arr[b],c)
```

to insert element c into b-th lsit while keeping it sorted, but it iserts c into every list in arr

Later on I discovered that regular incert works like that too if I use

```
arr[b].isert(idx,c)
```

Is there a possibility to change the structure of arr to continue using bisect.insort?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

apparently when I do

```
arr = [[]]*n
```

it creates a list of n references to one empty list.
Instead I should have used

```
arr = [[] for i in range(3)]
```